# Why couldn't the Dark Release: Inhaling Maw absorb Rasen Shuriken Technique ?

Tags: naruto

Towards the end of [Naruto Shippūden 3: Inheritors of the Will of Fire](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Shipp%C5%ABden_3:_Inheritors_of_the_Will_of_Fire) Hiruko failed to absorb Naruto's rasenshuriken technique.

[Dark Release: Inhaling Maw](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Release:_Inhaling_Maw) technique is described as a technique which can forcibly extract the physical and spiritual energy of another ninja, even from a considerable distance. Yet it is mentioned that when Hiruko tried to absorb Naruto's Wind Release: Rasenshuriken, he was unable to combine the shape and nature manipulation, and the technique fell apart, meaning the user of this technique has to match the level and nature of the jutsu he's trying to absorb.

But Hiruko could simply drain Naruto of his chakra, disabling him from using whatever technique he had up his sleeve.

I'm feeling a gap here. Without understanding what happened there,(I can understand Naruto being gutsy, forceful and all), but a forceful ending of the movie would make me feel a bit unhappy ! I'll be glad if someone explains it to me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, take all of this with a grain of salt. The movie is entirely filler, and was not explicitly explained anywhere.

When Hiroku tried to absorb and use the Rasenshuriken, the process of combining this specific nature with that specific shape was too hard for him. Remember that Naruto needs 2 additional clones and a significant amount of time to generate a rasenshuriken. When Hiroku tried, the technique blew up in his hand, and he didn't have the time to do anything else.

As for Hiroku disabling Naruto's chakra, remember that Naruto is the jinchuuriki of the Nine Tails, even if Hiroku could absorb such an incredible amount of chakra without being overwhelmed, The Nine Tails' hatred infused chakra is poisonous.

On a more "producer"ish note, Naruto had to win somehow...

Comment: Oh! so it was either by the rasenshuriken or the Kyuubi ... my questions could go on .. like for example Hiruko had 3 other Kekkei Genkai, and could do better than taking a head on from that rasenshuriken .. :-)

Comment: Yes, Hiroku could have evaded with the Swift element and attacked from behind. But he was confident that he could have used the Rasenshuriken. He was overconfident in his ability to absorb Ninjutsu.

Comment: ok .. :D I could speculate over Hiruko's strategy all day, and wonder how long drawn that battle could be. But Naruto is the hero after all .. accepted peacefully ! Thanks ! :-)

Comment: oh! there is one more thing .. about Hiruko absorbing the Kyuubi chakra .. at that point Naruto still wasn't in possession of the demon's chakra, and the Eight Trigrams Seal only allows a limited rate of flow of the nine tail's chakra into Naruto's chakra network, but if Hiruko started to absorbed enough of Naruto's *blue*-chakra, the Kyuubi could take that chance and run rampant, since there wouldn't be enough *blue*-chakra to keep the *red*-chakra in check. This would lead to a completely different scenario. :o